# Unknown user 2003 running haiduc command in my vps

Tags: top, ps

There is an unknown user named 2003 running command haiduc on my vps when i run the command 'top'. However the user 2003 does not exist. Does anybody know what this is?

[image]

Comment: Using my favorite search engine for the terms "haiduc linux" suggests that this is a cryptocurrency mining bot (exploit).  You've likely been compromised, so you need to nuke this installation and start from scratch. I suggest learning how to responsibly protect your VPS from intruders, so that you don't become part of a malicious botnet for which you could be liable for causing damages to others. At the very least you should disable SSH login as root.  Don't reuse any of the same credentials with the new install and change any credentials you might have ever input into this VPS.

Comment: Thank you, but how is it possible that the user '2003' does not exist when i search my list users?

Comment: According to articles about this exploit, it's usually paired with software that obscures what it's doing.  This is why securing your system up front is so important- if someone gains root access they can do ANYTHING. Please disconnect the VPS ASAP.

Comment: The root login to vps was disabled. All logins with sudo access requires 2fa. Could this have been done without sudo or root?